# How to expect the creation of an array with PowerMock

Tags: java, junit, easymock, powermock

I'm currently trying to test a method that creates an array of objects, and then executes a method on a object with the array of objects as the parameter.  Everytime I try to do it, I keep getting a `constructorNotFound` error. I apologize if its unclear, but hopefully you will be able to understand what I'm talking about with my example below.

```
public class Bar {
    public final String name;
    public final Bar[] barList;

    public Bar(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        barList = null;
    }

    public Bar update(Bar[] bar) {
        Bar newBar = new Bar(name);
        newBar.barList = bar;
        return newBar;
    }
}

public class Foo {
    public static Bar internalMethod( Bar oldBar) {

        // in reality this method does a lot more
        // I just kept it simple for demonstration purposes
        Bar[] bar = new Bar[2];
        oldBar = oldBar.update(bar);
        // about 15-20 method calls with oldBar as a parameter
        // and require mocking

         return oldBar;
    }
}
```

Here is the test class:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Bar[].class)
public class testFoo {

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        Bar[] barArr = new Bar[2];
        PowerMock.expectNew(Bar[].class).andReturn(barArr);
        PowerMock.replay(Bar[].class);

        Bar bar = new Bar("name");
        Bar newBar = Foo.internalMethod(bar);

        // assume there are many more checks to make sure that the appropriate
        // methods were called and the changes were made

        assertEquals("name", newBar.name);
        assertNull(newBar.barList[0]);
        assertNull(newBar.barList[1]);
    }
}
```

**Does anyone know how to deal with a situation like this?**

I realize that the class design isn't ideal, but, unfortunately, I do not get to change it.  I'm using PowerMock 1.4.10 and I do not have access to mockito framework.

Comment: I honestly don't understand what you are doing here. If you really intend to test a method, it doesn't make sense to manipulate what the method itself does. I would understand if you tried to mock what the method does in order to test some other code that actually uses your `methodToTest` - but this makes no sense to me. Also, `methodToTest` as it is listed here doesn't do anything (except that it adds some work for the garbage collector). So... sorry, but I don't understand what you are talking about.

Comment: I've updated the question and method `methodToTest` so that the situation is a little more realistic since my original example was oversimplified as @skirsch pointed out.  I've also added in some comments to clarify where I have taken some liberties to simplify the code.

Comment: Okay. I guess you cannot do that; look [here](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor) and search for "array". I'm not sure what you want to achieve (seems like you want to mock exactly what is done anyway? Is it about the expectations?), but still I think if you want to test that method, you should not mess with its internals.
The funny thing is that the asserts look like your actually testing the `Bar.update` method; but I assume that's because of the simplifications...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm. Can't you just mock the `Bar` instance you pass as an argument, expecting `update` to be called with a `Bar[]` array, returning whatever you want, and so on?

This could look like this:

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    Bar bar = new Bar("name").update(new Bar[2]);
    Bar barMock = EasyMock.createMock(Bar.class);
    EasyMock.expect(barMock.update(EasyMock.aryEq(new Bar[2]))).andReturn(bar);
    EasyMock.replay(barMock);

    Bar newBar = Foo.internalMethod(barMock);

    EasyMock.verify(barMock);
    assertEquals("name", newBar.name);
    assertNull(newBar.barList[0]);
    assertNull(newBar.barList[1]);
}
```

This too, looks a bit funny as the asserts all check the `Bar` instance being set up at the start of the test. But given that `internalMethod` does a lot more, it verifies that the returned `Bar` instance is actually not tampered with.

Comment: I think you are now understanding what I'm struggling to explain.  I want to know how to expect `update` to be called with a `Bar[]` array.  What is the syntax for something like that?  The google groups syntax suggested that it may not be possible. [link](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor)

Comment: I think that might work! I've never used the EasyMock.aryEq before but based on the API, I don't see any reason why it wouldn't work.  I'll try it out and let you know what happens.